Scrollbar with dynamic height in css flexbox layout
Let's assume I have a flexbox layout like below.

I want to make the #content div taking all the available space without breaking anything about scrollbar. I tried height: 100% in #content but that pushes the #navbar away from the viewport. What can I do to make this work? Any suggestions?
For your convenience, I linked my jsfiddle here.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

On of the easiest solutions is to calc() the flex-basis of a content div: subtract flex-basis of #navbar from #container's height.
#content {
  flex-basis: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

Snippet:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 30px;
}

#main {
  background: #eee;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

#middle {
  background: #777;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  background: #aaa;
  flex-basis: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow: auto;
}

#right {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 25px;
}
<div id="container">
  <div id="navbar"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">
      <div id="content">
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
        <p>paragraph 3</p>
        <p>paragraph 4</p>
        <p>paragraph 5</p>
        <p>paragraph 6</p>
        <p>paragraph 7</p>
        <p>paragraph 8</p>
        <p>paragraph 9</p>
        <p>paragraph 10</p>
        <p>paragraph 11</p>
        <p>paragraph 12</p>
        <p>paragraph 13</p>
        <p>paragraph 14</p>
        <p>paragraph 15</p>
        <p>paragraph 16</p>
        <p>paragraph 17</p>
        <p>paragraph 18</p>
        <p>paragraph 19</p>
        <p>paragraph 20</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>




Seems I am so dumb as couldn't debug this simple issue on my own. Thanks anyways. Much appreciated.
